# Windows 2008R2 raising low memory events when 50GB of RAM is available

Tags: windows, memory-management

Observed Windows 2008 R2 is generating KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition events when there is 50GB of RAM available and all processes are using just around 18GB.

Not able to find the reason why windows is complaining when there is tons of RAM freely available?

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Answer (score 3):

Even if you got all that amount of RAM, it could be because you've got low hard disk space as Windows requires more disk space for paging.
It can also be related to the version of your Windows 2008 R2 Edition. Refer to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2008_R2#System_requirements) for more informations.

Comment: I have around 50GB of empty space in my C drive...

Comment: Maybe it's that so, If you have 50GB of RAM for example, Windows will allocate by default 1.5 x (Amount of your RAM). It can vary depending of your configuration, anyway, the best advice that I can give you is to free some Disk Space and watch if the system will still raise that error.